# Simple update query taking too long - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I have a table with 28 million rows that I want to update. It has around 60 columns and a ID column  (primary key) with an index created on it. I created four new columns and I want to populate them with the data from four columns from other table which also has an ID column with an index created on it. Both tables have the same amount of rows and just the primary key and the index on the IDENTI column. The query has been running for 15 hours and since it is high priority work, we are starting to get nervous about it and we don't have so much time to experiment with queries. We have never update a table so big (7 GB), so we are not sure if this amount of time is normal.

This is the query:

```
UPDATE consolidated
SET IDEDUP2=uni.IDEDUP2
USE21=uni.USE21
USE22=uni.USE22
PESOXX2=uni.PESOXX2
FROM uni_group uni, consolidated con
WHERE con.IDENTI=uni.IDENTI
```

How can I make it faster? Is it possible? If not, is there a way to check how much longer it is going to take (without killing the process)?

Just as additional information, we have ran before much more complex queries for 3 million row tables (postgis) and It has taken it about 15 hours as well.

Comment: are you sure both table have an index  on  IDENTI column ?

Comment: Yes, both of them have pkey (set when I created the tables) and an index created by a regular CREATE INDEX...ON...() query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **not** repeat the target table in the FROM clause. Your statement creates a cartesian join of the `consolidated` table with itself, which is not what you want.

You should use the following:

```
UPDATE consolidated con
   SET IDEDUP2=uni.IDEDUP2
       USE21=uni.USE21
       USE22=uni.USE22
       PESOXX2=uni.PESOXX2
FROM uni_group uni
WHERE con.IDENTI = uni.IDENTI
```

Comment: Does this affect the running time by a lot? Just so I know if it is worth killing the process and restart it or just wait at this point

Comment: @A.T.: yes I assume this would affect the running time substantially. The bigger the target table is, the worse your unintentional cross join will be

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I write for anyone with this problem. The solution you proposed reduced the running time from 15 hours (and still not finished) to 10 minutes.